# Firebase not receiving any data after returning from background state

Tags: ios, firebase, nest-api

I've created a Today Extension widget that uses the Nest Firebase api. Somehow, in some cases, the Firebase object does not receive any updates on objects it was subscribed to after the extension was suspended (not used) for a while.

After switching off/on wifi, or toggling flight mode, the connection seems to be re-established and the subscriptions start working again.

Is there a way to check the current state of the connection, and forcing a reconnect on 'viewDidLoad'?

Comment: You can monitor `.info/connected` to check the current state of the connection.

Comment: Which object has this property? And if it is disconnected, is there a way to force reconnect?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: Thanks, this brought me to the iOS documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html